# Swift: Can't import Frameworks in Xcode, running into error: 'no such a moudle' (installed using cocoapods)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, forms, cocoapods

Its frustrating seeing this error every time i use cocoa-pods. The only thing that works with cocoa-pods is 'Firebase SDK' but when i install any other framework such as JSQMessages or Eureka forms or any other framework i got an error 'No such a module" ... Its not the first time I work with these frameworks I did before and it was working correctly in fact I still got my previous projects installed with JSQMesgs, eurka..etc and its working fine till now. For the new projects it doesn't work/import in xcode anymore it is frustrating that I can't run it with this error ... not sure if its xcode or the cocopods .. I have  tried instaling using terminal then uninstall and reinstall again with cocoapods application.  I cleaned my build, change deployment target several times, and nothing worked so please if any one could share the same problems faced or advice me on how to avoid them or any alternatives to cocoapods.

```
deployment target 10.3 my xcode version 8.3.3 swift 3 macOS Sierra 10.12.5


# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FinalProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FinalProject

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
pod 'FirebaseStorage'
pod 'ProgressHUD'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'Eureka'
pod 'Former'
pod 'SwiftForms'

end
```

Please help.

Comment: same thing happens with me many times best deal I ever made with this is either clean the project or quite the current project and open again and run again

Comment: Yea that solves the problems, I got that error message a lot

Comment: can you install cocoa pod in terminal inside your project library?

Comment: yeah i can install it but when i try to use it in my project xcode doesn't recognize if its installed or not (cant import in the module list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the project.

The Xcode editor doesn't recognize modules coming from the Pods until after they've been built for the first time.

If that doesn't work for you, please share a screen shot of the issue, or even better, a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to work with SwiftyStoreKit.
I finally manage to solve my problem and hope that sharing the solution will help someone.

I tried everything was suggested until I realised that I was loading the pod in the wrong target, (in the pod file itself.)

After I repaired the pod file, run again pod install, and, voila, the xcode recognised the pod.